# Pasting text copied from a PDF?

Tags: encoding, adobe, acrobat

I have a PDF file, which contains only text.

When I copy some text like below:

```
payload
```

And try to paste it in Notepad++, getting boxes like below:

I tried to change encoding in Notepad++, but not able to see actual text.

This is happening with one particular PDF file.

I have verified that PDF's security allows copying:

[image]

I found one more thing, if I search some text in the PDF, the find command is not able to find the text though the searched term is in the document.

How can I paste text as copied from such files?

Comment: Those boxes are default  glyphs (not present in used font) as your text seems to be from Unicode private range: `U+100189`, `U+100102`, `U+1001C7`, `U+10016F`, `U+10017D`, `U+100102`, `U+10011A`.

Comment: Next time you have a question like this, add the PDF tag. You would have gotten an answer much quicker.

Answer (score 0):

Though you don't include the PDF file in your question, it's fair to assume the problem is what it always is with such files - the PDF file does not provide a correct character code to Unicode translation table.

In such files, searching doesn't work and copy / paste doesn't work either, because Acrobat doesn't know what these things on the page are supposed to mean.

The problem is usually unfixable - meaning, there isn't generally something you can do to fix this particular document so that it will start to work.

A possible work-around - and this will sound stupid - is to convert the PDF to images and perform OCR on it. The OCR algorithm, if it handles the file correctly, will normally insert proper text that can be searched or copied.